# Dependence of \write18 to svg-package

Tags: luatex, shell-escape

In the following MWE I am experiencing a (to me) very weird dependence of the `\write18` command and the `svg` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{svg}

\begin{document}
    \immediate\write18{echo 'test' >> test.txt}

    Some content
\end{document}
```

When compiling the document as provided the file `test.txt` is created with the proper content. However if I comment out the `\usepackage{svg}` in my document header this file does not get created.

I am using `latexmk` with `lualatex` for compilation (with shell-escape enabled of course) and I even tried compiling the document from the console via `lualatex --shell-escape test.tex`.
When using `pdflatex` the problem disappears.

When using the console I see the `echo 'test' >> test.txt` being printed to the console which indicates (to me) that `\write18` is doing its job as one would expect. However (as said above) the file does not get created unless I use the `svg` package.

I assume that its some `\RequirePackage{...}` inside the `svg` package that does the trick.

Does somebody have an explanation to this or may I have encountered a bug in `lualatex`?

Comment: Behavior confirmed, but see yudal-nkt's answer, which shows how to solve it. Not a bug, just unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LuaTeX 0.87 and newer supports write streams up to 256, so `\write18` is not treated specially anymore. The LaTeX3 project prepares [`shellesc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/shellesc) package, which is loaded by `svg` package, to provide a uniform interface to execute external commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\begin{document}
\ShellEscape{echo 'foo' >> foo.txt}
\end{document}
```

This package also enables us to use the old syntax `\write18{...}` in recent LuaTeX, but it should be noted that it is always executed `\immediate`ly. If you need to run commands at the time of `\shipout`, use `\DelayedShellEscape` instead.